# Using Flattr API v2 with iOS

Tags: ios, oauth, flattr

I'm currently building an iOS application and want to include Flattr-Support over the Flattr-API v2.

I've already created my application at https://flattr.com/apps/ and got the key and secret.

The problem is that I have to provide a callback-URL in the application-settings at flattr even if I select "client" as application type. In addition only http://... callback-URLs seem to be allowed in the input field so I can't set a callback URL to open my application (something like myApp://...)

How do I implement the Flattr oAuth process for client applications?
Are there any detailed instructions how to implement the flattr-authentication with a non-web-based / iOS application?

I planned to use the JDG OAuthConsumer library but this doesn't seem to work - any other iOS librarys I could use?

Comment: Seems like I found the solution myself using the gtm-oauth2 library. I'll check if it really works and describe the solution tomorrow.

Comment: Looking forward to the description. I answered you question anyhow to  give an idea of you we intended the oauth2 flow.  Good luck and don't hesitate to ask if something is unclear!

Comment: Sorry but won't be able to answer today. I hope to get back to it tomorrow afternoon

Comment: Did not get it to work yet. No error during oauth authorization process but I get a 500 Response-Code if I try to flattr a thing with the https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/things/:id/flattr URL and my authentication token

Comment: There was an error in the flattr resource. It should be fixed now. Try to flattr the same thing again!

Comment: Successfully flattered a thing form my application. Thanks!

Comment: Just an important non-technical note: Apple has started to reject apps that use the flattr API, so you probably shouldn't use it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411720/flattr-sdk-for-ios

Answer (score 3):

A short description of my implementation using the Flattr API v2 to flattr a thing from my iOS application:

I'm currently using the "Google Toolbox for Mac - OAuth 2 Controllers":
http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/

Create a Token to be authenticated:

```
- (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)flattrAuth {

NSURL *tokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://flattr.com/oauth/token"];
// We'll make up an arbitrary redirectURI.  The controller will watch for
// the server to redirect the web view to this URI, but this URI will not be
// loaded, so it need not be for any actual web page.
NSString *redirectURI = @"http://localhost/"; //for me localhost with / didn't work

GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth;
auth = [GTMOAuth2Authentication authenticationWithServiceProvider:@"MyApplication"
                                                         tokenURL:tokenURL
                                                      redirectURI:redirectURI
                                                         clientID:clientKey
                                                     clientSecret:clientSecret];
return auth;
}
```

Create a ViewController to authenticate the token:

```
- (GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch*)getSignInViewController{
GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = [self flattrAuth];

// Specify the appropriate scope string, if any, according to the service's API documentation
auth.scope = @"flattr";

NSURL *authURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://flattr.com/oauth/authorize"];

GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController;
viewController = [[[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithAuthentication:auth
                                                              authorizationURL:authURL
                                                              keychainItemName:keychainItemName
                                                                      delegate:self
                                                              finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)] autorelease];

return viewController;
}
```

and the delegate method:

```
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
  finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
             error:(NSError *)error {
if (error != nil) {
    DLog(@"Flattr sign-in failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    DLog(@"Flattr Signin success");
    authToken = [auth retain];
}
}
```

You can display the Viewcontroller in your application - it  displays the flattr-login to the user so he can authenticate the application.

You can flattr a thing with the authentication token this way:

```
NSString* flattrURL = @"https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/things/%qi/flattr";
NSURL* u = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:flattrURL, item.flattrThingID]];
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:u];
[authToken authorizeRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSError *error){
    if (error == nil) {
        // the request has been authorized
        NSURLConnection* connection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];

        if(!connection){
            //TODO: handle error
        } else {
            [connection start];
        }
    } else {
        //TODO: handle error
    }
}];
```

Now implement the NSURLConnectection delegate methods and parse the JSON responses.

The GTMOAuth2 library allows you to save the authenticated token to the keychain. Look at their introduction at http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction#Retrieving_Authorization_from_the_Keychain for instructions.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I'm glad that you got it to work and that we could pin a few bugs along the way.

Answer (score 1):

When you wan't to authenticate a desktop/mobile app you would wan't to use the oauth2 implicit grant flow. As you register your flattr application use a application specific URI that will callback to your application, ex. `iphone-application://oauth-callback`.

When you authenticate the application with us you use the `response_type` `token` instead of `code`. This will create a token at once and redirect you back to your application.

Ex. request URL: `https://flattr.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=2134&redirect_uri=iphone-application://oauth-callback&response_type=token`

If the resource owner will authorize your application we will send a HTTP 302 and redirect you back to your redirect uri.

Ex. response 302 Location: `iphone-application://oauth-callback#access_token=e5oNJ4917WAaJaO4zvoVV2dt3GYClPzp&token_type=bearer`

Currently we don't have any detailed documentation explaining how to do the implicit grant but we are working on the documentation. Meanwhile i'm all ears.

https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client is a iOS oauth2 library but I don't know if it's any good.

Comment: That's how I initially thought it should work. But are you sure I can set iphone-application://oauth-callback in the applcation settings?
Only URL I was able to set was http://...

Answer (score 0):

This one looks good: https://github.com/neonichu/FlattrKit