# Flattr SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, flattr

Is there an official (or otherwise well-maintained) iOS library to use the Flattr API? If so, does it include a comfortable SSO-solution similar to what Facebook offers, where other apps can delegate authentication to the official app?

Comment: It seems as if Apple won't let you use Flattr in iOS apps, though: http://blog.flattr.net/2012/05/apple-rejected-flattr-and-its-not-the-end/

Answer (score 2):

I've made an app (not released) with Flattr. I thought about writing a lib, but then decided that [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) was enough. OAuth 2.0 is pretty easy to implement yourself. And a wrapper for the API feels kinda superfluous. :) RestKit also gives you goodies like CoreData backing and object mapping!

Answer (score 0):

This one looks good: https://github.com/neonichu/FlattrKit